# How Can I Update wp_enqueue_scripts () From WordPress Option Page Radio Buttons

Tags: plugin-development, theme-options, settings-api

Can you please take a look at this script and let me know how can I update the `wp_enqueue_scripts ()` in theme `functions.php` based on radio select in custom option page?

what I have in function.php is

```
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'Map', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/Google.js' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
```

Now I need to change the

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'Map', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/Google.js' );
```

to

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'Map', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ESRI.js' );
```

Or the other way around on changing the Radio in

```
<?php

function map-settings()
{
    add_settings_section("section", "Section", null, "map");
    add_settings_field("style-radio", "Map Radio Buttons", "map_radio_display", "map", "section");  
    register_setting("section", "style-radio");
}

function map_radio_display()
{
   ?>
        <input type="radio" name="style-radio" value="1" <?php checked(1, get_option('style-radio'), true); ?>>ERSI Map
        <input type="radio" name="style-radio" value="2" <?php checked(2, get_option('style-radio'), true); ?>>Google Map
   <?php
}

add_action("admin_init", "map-settings");

function map_op_page()
{
  ?>
      <div class="wrap">
         <h1>Map Script</h1>

         <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
               settings_fields("section");

               do_settings_sections("map");

               submit_button(); 
            ?>
         </form>
      </div>
   <?php
}

function menu_item()
{
  add_submenu_page("options-general.php", "Map", "Map", "manage_options", "map", "map_op_page"); 
}

add_action("admin_menu", "menu_item");
```

Comment: where is this code of the script you want to remove ? in a theme or a plugin ?

Comment: Hi mmm, they are in Theme `functions.php`

Comment: if the theme is not updatable, you can modify it directly. otherwise create a child theme and use this function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

Comment: `if the theme is not updatable, you can modify it directly` can you please let me know what do you mean by this?

Comment: If your theme was downloaded from, for example, the [Theme Directory](https://wordpress.org/themes/), all changes you make to that theme will disappear after you update it. This does not happen with homemade themes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$mapScript = ( get_option('style-radio') === 1 ) ? "ESRI.js" : "Google.js";
wp_enqueue_script( 'Map', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/' . $mapScript );
```

Comment: Just dumping code is not considered a good answer. Please, explain it and how it answers the question.